# What kind of fish is Jinbe?

Tags: one-piece

After having a first look at Jinbei at Impel Down I was wondering, what kind of a fish is he?

[image: Jinbe]

(Since fish-men are half human - half fish). **Arlong was a blue saw-shark**, but Jinbe doesn't appear to resemble a shark so I was wondering, what kind of a fish he could be? Also, are the two white things sticking out of his mouth teeth or elephant-like tusks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jinbe is a **whale shark fishman**.

> Jinbe is a **large blue whale shark fishman** with a stocky build similar to a sumo wrestler and a face that is commonly associated with various Japanese demons such as the [**oni**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oni_%28folklore%29)

Focus on oni because it's related to his two white fangs.

> He also possesses **two tusk-like conical lower fangs** associated with Oni as well; the rest of his teeth from the upper and lower rows are pretty much the same, albeit much smaller. He also has a severe underbite, which makes room for his huge fangs.

[image]

Source for above quotes: [Jinbe - The One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jinbe#Appearance) (emphasis added)

Comment: Please remember to include a link to any source from which you directly copy text.

Comment: I'll include the sources next time. Thanks!!